# Why doesn't this algorithm make sense when tracing?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

I've been tracing this code for quite some time

I understand it.  But at some point, it stopped make sense to me.

In `name` and `typed`, position 0 is the same letter so increment both j and i (`j++` and `i++`).  i = 1, j = 1.

In position 1, they aren't the same so ONLY increment j.  i = 1, j = 2.

In position 2, they aren't the same so ONLY increment j.  i = 1, j = 3.
This is where I'm stuck.

How come in the console it's also incrementing `i` (`i = 2, j = 3`) as well?  The letters are different which means only increment `j`.  May someone please point out what I'm not seeing?

This is the Leetcode problem I'm doing https://leetcode.com/problems/long-pressed-name/

Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
    public String name = "alex";
    public String typed = "aaleex";
    public boolean isLongPressedName(String name, String typed) {
        if(name == null) return false;
        if(typed == null) return false;

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(;i < name.length() && j < typed.length();) {
            if(name.charAt(i) == typed.charAt(j)) {
                j++;
                i++;
                System.out.println("END IF");
            } else {
                j++;
                System.out.println("END ELSE");
            }
            System.out.println("i => " + i);
            System.out.println("j => " + j);


            if(i != name.length() && j == typed.length()) {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output in console:

```
END IF
i => 1
j => 1
END ELSE
i => 1
j => 2
END IF
i => 2
j => 3
END IF
i => 3
j => 4
END ELSE
i => 3
j => 5
END IF
i => 4
j => 6
```

Comment: The best way to trace these things is using a debugger. The debugger would have shown you that `name.charAt(i)` is the same as `typed.charAt(j)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself, `i` was not incremented. So we will still be looking at the *first* index of `name`:

```
 if(name.charAt(i) == typed.charAt(j))
```

So on the third iteration we are comparing `name` at the first index (`l`) and `typed` at the second index, (`l`) and they *are* the same, so we increment both `i` and `j`

Or to visualize this:

```
alex    //i == 0
^
aaleex  //j == 0
^
```

Both are the same, so both get incremented:

```
alex    //i == 1
 ^
aaleex  //j == 1
 ^
```

They are not, so only the second is incremented:

```
alex    //i == 1
 ^
aaleex  //j == 2
  ^
```

Now they are pointing to the same letter, so both are incremented again

```
alex    //i == 2
  ^
aaleex  //j == 3
   ^
```

Both are the same, both incremented

```
alex    //i == 3
   ^
aaleex  //j == 4
    ^
```

Not the same, only `j` incremented

```
alex    //i == 3
   ^
aaleex  //j == 5
     ^
```

Both the same, but we have reached the end of the `String`

Comment: It's always the small things that stump me for the longest, thank you for this.  I understand now :D.  *gives hug*.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do a simple dry run and you'll know what the issue is.

```
if(name.charAt(i) == typed.charAt(j))
```

When i is 1 so charAt(i) => 'l'
So when j is 2 so charAt(j) => 'l' so both will be incremented.

Then both would be incremented by 1. So i would become 2 and j would become 3.

```
a l e x

0 1 2 3


a a l e e x

0 1 2 3 4 5

i 0 = j 0

i 1 = j 2

i 2 = j 3

i 3 = j 5
```